# Как проверить, является ли локальный пользователь администратором?

Tags: c#, администрирование, права

Здравствуйте, вопрос такой:
В общем у меня есть список локальных пользователей компьютера, и надо пробежаться по нему, выбрав при этом только администраторов. Так вот, как средствами C# можно проверить, является ли пользователь администратором по его имени(он не должен сейчас находиться в системе)?

Comment: Администратор понятие растяжимое. Вам нужно проверить входит ли пользователь в группу "Администраторы"?

Comment: а если винда англоязычная, то группа будет называться по-английски. А если компьютер входит в домен, то там названия администраторских групп уже из двух слов. А также ничего не мешает создать группу в винде с произвольным названием, и дать ей привилегии дающие право на выполнение задач, которые обычно разрешены *Администратор*у

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из списка локальных пользователей выбираются те кто входит в группу `"Администраторы"`.

```
DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName);
DirectoryEntry admGroup = localMachine.Children.Find("Администраторы", "group");
object members = admGroup.Invoke("members", null);

Console.WriteLine("Администраторы:");
foreach (object groupMember in (IEnumerable)members)
{
    DirectoryEntry member = new DirectoryEntry(groupMember);
    Console.WriteLine(member.Name);
}
```